# timing a method's duration

Tags: objective-c

I have a splash that displays at my app's startup while it loads data from a Web query. I'd like to make sure the splash displays for at least 3 seconds, but sometimes the load query takes less than this. However, I don't want this 3 seconds added to the time it takes to load the web data; I just want to make sure the minimum is 3 seconds.

In other words, can I time how long it takes to load the data, then maybe set a delay for the difference between that load time and 3 seconds, and make the splash hang on (using a selctor or something) for that extra amount of time?

Comment: Why make the user wait longer than they have to?

Comment: well, i agree, but we have a really really nice splash screen that has some product branding on it and we want to make sure it is seen for more than a fraction of a second.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you any more on this, but I urge you to re-think your decision -- it can turn out to be a terrible design flaw: your users will (most likely) not appreciate increased loading times.

Comment: Three seconds is a bit long, but not the worst I've seen. I actually enjoy some splash screens because they add a sense of professionalism to the app. As a user though, I usually get tired of waiting longer than 2 seconds or so. 3 is not too bad. The splash screen on the iphone game Paladog, for example, is around 8 seconds in my experience. Yuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that instead of doing it that way, you start a 3 second long timer when you start the load query.  When each finishes, set a boolean to say that one finished and call a method that checks if both are done yet; if so, it's time to close the splash window. (sorry, no code examples - I'm not familiar with Objective C)

Comment: NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 target:self selector:@selector(checkIfDoneLoading) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

Comment: In checkIfDoneLoading: --- if (WebView.loading == FALSE) { // Go on to next screen. }

Comment: You don't actually need to check from the webview's side, because you don't need to finish before the timer. If the timer is done when the webview isn't, then it waits for the webview. Otherwise the webview finishes first, and the timer moves on immediately.